# FOSS Script for unlocking PDF for printing

Tags: pdf, software-rec, pdf-unlocking

I have some Govt documents, which needs to be unlocked for printing. I have about 300 such documents. Do you know any FOSS software which can be used for this, it would be great if it can run in batch mode.

Answer (score 2):

[Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) gives you the option to ignore DRM of any kind. You could also try the [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) or a lightweight-reader like [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/index.html) which may ignore DRM.

Answer (score 2):

xpdf can be built to ignore DRM while printing.  It includes pdftops, so you can probably use this command line.